# MySQL code error

Tags: mysql, code

Can someone please tell what is wrong with below SQL code?

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    student_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    major VARCHAR(20),
    );
```

Comment: Please add the error message to your question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the comma after the last column declaration.

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
    student_id  INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name  VARCHAR(20),
    major       VARCHAR(20)
);
```